# What is best practices to store dynamically uploaded files(Where to upload server folder or sub folder)?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, file-upload

I have a web system users will upload files(1 GB Max). Right now i have hosted my web site in the root directory. So is it good to store uploaded files into the hosted web server root folder/Uploads ?.(Will it slow the web site to load).
What is the best practice to store dynamically uploaded files?

Comment: What is the role of those uploaded files?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to store the uploaded files in the same folder with your application files.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias What do you think is the best practice ?

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin purpose is to upload image zip files to some users and another party will download then edit them and again upload to server as a new zip. Basically i wanna store and download when needed.

Comment: I think that storing the files in a subfolder of the application (dedicated for uploaded files only) is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction) instead.

- If you store your files with the server, it will continuously throw errors in case there is no more free disk space available.
- When you want to move the application into another server, all your files must be also moved.
- You will stress the server every time a user wants to download some files
- Blob Storage allows replication and high availability.